# StencilJS display string as HTML

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

I need to display html elements based on a file type. The html element creates icons. Now I only get a string.

```
{
   isArray(data.Attachments)
   ?
   data.Attachments.map(attachment =>
     getIcon(attachment.FileExtension)
   )
   : ''
}

const getIcon = (icon: string): string => {
  if (icon) {
    return '<span class="icon-nolink video-link"></span>'
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show the larger context of the code. Are you calling this from render()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To output unescaped HTML you can use the `innerHTML` attribute:

```
render() {
    return <div innerHTML={getIcon('name')}></div>
}
```

Source: https://stenciljs.com/docs/templating-jsx/#complex-template-content

Comment: I used Handlebars and they have something like {{{html}}} ... but this is good enough. Thank you.